# printfn and debug output in F# WPF VS2012 project

Tags: wpf, f#, visual-studio-2012

I'm experimenting with WPF in F#. Visual Studio 2012 has several online project templates for that:

- F# & C# Hybrid MVVM. Standard C# WPF executable for views and f# libs for the rest.
- Pure F# MVVM
- Pure F# Empty

I started with the first option, but later switched to the pure f# solution.
And there is one issue I can't get around with.

I don't see the printfn results in the VS Output window anymore. Though if I put a breakpoint I see that the code gets reached.

Here is a sample:

```
module MainApp
open System
open System.Windows
open System.Windows.Controls
open FSharpx

type MainWindow = XAML<"MainWindow.xaml">

let loadWindow() =
    let window = MainWindow()

    printfn "%s" "Test"

    window.Root

[<STAThread>]
(new Application()).Run(loadWindow()) |> ignore
```

That's the App.fs created by the template with a single addition - printfn. Output - nothing.

I wonder what's makes it different. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline.aspx) to write to the VS Output window. The [TRACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983575%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) constant must be defined, which it is by default in Debug.

The [printfn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370571.aspx) writes to stdout which is the console window in a console application.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can set the project as a Console Application, so you'll have a console window as well as the WPF window, and you can use printfn as usual.